# On dismiss a view controller pop me to rootview controller

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

So My problem is on dismiss a presented view controller, nil the navigation stack. I checked the navigation stack before and after the 
dismiss 
Hierarchy is tab controller -> SettingController -> ItemListController -> AddItemController 
on addItem present the gallery controller and after dismiss the gallery controller navigation stack get nil

```
  let gallery = GalleryController()
    gallery.delegate = self
    present(gallery, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and the code for dismiss is

```
controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

where my tab code is

```
  self.viewControllers = [createLiveOrder(), createFeed(), createHistoryController() ,createSettingController()]
```

create a controller like this for tab where the identifier is the navigation view controller

```
func createSettingController() -> UIViewController {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoard.setting.rawValue, bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Controller.initController.rawValue)
        vc.tabBarItem = setting
        return vc
    }
```

But when I set the storyboard to setting to works fine(I take tab veiw controller on the different storyboard and  setting module on different storyboard)

Comment: try using delegate to pass control to tabbar from GalleryController

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the main reason behind it. But From assign an array of viewController in viewWillAppear of subClass of UITabController didn't work. but when I controller from StoryBoard reference from the Storyboard work fine for .eg

Code creating issue is

```
self.viewControllers = [createLiveOrder(), createFeed(), createHistoryController() ,createSettingController()
```

where created and assign each controller is

```
func createSettingController() -> UIViewController {
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: StoryBoard.setting.rawValue, bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Controller.initController.rawValue)
    vc.tabBarItem = setting
    return vc
}
```

on same Assing controller from storyboard works fine

> Note:- Storyboard delegates are assigned in subclass